# Change Style of rows created by ListView in itemCreated event

Tags: c#, asp.net, listviewitem

When render a databound ListView I want to dynamically set the background colour of each row depending on the results, in my case Red, Orange and Green.

```
        protected void ListView1_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow myRow;
        DataRowView myRowView;
        myRowView = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        myRow = myRowView.Row;

        if (myRow[2].ToString().CompareTo("") == 1)
        {
          // Colour coding here..    
        }

    }
```

Is it possible to reach the TR tag for each row to change the style?

Many thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution to my problem, with some good help from Brian.

I have a ListView and I added an id tag (trRow) and tag runat="server" like this:

```
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <tr id="trRow" runat="server" style="background-color:#FFF8DC;">
```

In code behind it looks like this:

```
        protected void ListView1_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow myRow;
        DataRowView myRowView;
        myRowView = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        myRow = myRowView.Row;

        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow myTR = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("trRow");

        if (myRow[2].ToString().CompareTo("") == 1)
        {
            myTR.Style.Value = "background-color:#FF0000;color: #000000;";
        } else
            myTR.Style.Value = "background-color:#00FF00;color: #000000;";

    }
```

Some of the logic in there is still not correct etc, just to show how I solved the issue to dynamically change the background color of each row.

Answer (score 1):

The TR tag would have to have runat="server" to use server-side code; however, you may be able to inject it in without that by examining the controls that are the child of the item; there's probably a Literal or LiteralControl with the HTML, and you can use string manipulation to inject...

Comment: Hi, do you mean by using the Sender or the ListViewItemEventArgs in ItemCreated event? Not 100% sure what you suggesting here. //Thanks

Comment: if you use a server side TR, use e.Item.FindControl("trid"); otherwise, I'm not 100% sure,  but I think the e.Item has a Controls collection, which you could loop through looking for the literal with the <TR> tag to inject.